# Azure Cloud Shell w/Windows Terminal limitations?

Tags: terminal, azure-cloud-shell

Where can I find the limitations/differences between running Azure Cloud Shell from the browser and Windows Terminal? For example, the "code xxx" command works differently when ran in the browser (opens up the editor) and Terminal (does nothing). Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: The current limitation for Azure Cloud shell are documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#general-limitations and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#general-limitations.

Comment: Regarding your specific query , to my understanding there isn't any limitation between running a command on Azure Cloud Shell from browser versus windows terminal. However I am reaching out to our internal team to confirm the same, will keep you updated. In the mean time if you have any example command where you saw it working differently please share that here. Thank you

Comment: Cloud Shell behaviour: (https://i.imgur.com/loqwHLI.png)  
Terminal Azure Cloud Shell behaviour: (https://i.imgur.com/br7sATr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ziv Rivkis - Apologies for delay in getting back to this thread. Post validation with our internal team it has been called out that we have Cloud Shell entry point limitation, which has been documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#supported-entry-point-limitations) now.

> Cloud Shell entry points beside the Azure portal, such as Visual
> Studio Code & Windows Terminal, do not support the use of commands
> that modify UX components in Cloud Shell, such as Code.

Hope the above information helps, please let us know if you have any further queries. Thank you